# SQL query based on date on an Excel file database

Tags: sql, database, vba, excel

I use ADO in order to execute SQL queries on an Excel file database and I have a problem while using the following query :

```
strQuery = "SELECT NUM,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR,STATE,LAST_MODIFICATION_DATE,LAST_MODIFIER,CATEGORY,MODEL_LABEL FROM [MySheet$] WHERE CREATION_DATE<='" + EndDateTextBox.Value + "' AND CREATION_DATE>='" + BeginDateTextBox.Value + "'"
```

The query is executed but I don't get any result when I enter 2010-01-01 in the BeginDateTextBox and 2016-01-01 in the EndDateTextBox, which is not normal because the dates in my database vary between 2014 and 2015.

Here is a screenshot of the CREATION_DATE column of my database :

[image]

PS : I know that using Excel files as a database is not the best practice but I'm told to do so.

Comment: Check if format for the dates. Try putting it as `01/01/2010` format instead to see if that works.

Comment: you have to convert the date into the correct date format (dd/mm/yyy hh:mm:ss)

Comment: I tried these two solutions, it doesn't work

Comment: are you getting any errors when you tried it @otus ?

Comment: No, I just don't get the results

Comment: have you tried the conversion as I suggested in the answer below?

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert dates to values, ADO can't recognize format of the cells in sheet, only values applicable. So final query should be something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM [MySheet$] WHERE CREATION_DATE <= 42370 AND CREATION_DATE >= 40179
```

you can achieve this using such method:

```
Sub test()
Dim DtStart as Long
DtStart = Clng(Cdate("2010-01-01"))
Msgbox DtStart
End Sub
```

so, the final SQL query will be:

```
strQuery = "SELECT NUM,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR,STATE,LAST_MODIFICATION_DATE,LAST_MODIFIER,CATEGORY,MODEL_LABEL " & _
           "FROM [MySheet$] " & _
           "WHERE CREATION_DATE <= " & CLng(CDate(EndDateTextBox.Value)) & _
           "  AND CREATION_DATE >= " & CLng(CDate(BeginDateTextBox.Value))
```

OR it can be like this:

```
strQuery = "SELECT NUM,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR,STATE,LAST_MODIFICATION_DATE,LAST_MODIFIER,CATEGORY,MODEL_LABEL " & _
           "FROM [MySheet$] " & _
           "WHERE CREATION_DATE BETWEEN " & _ 
            CLng(CDate(BeginDateTextBox.Value)) & " AND " & CLng(CDate(EndDateTextBox.Value))
```

here the test result:

[image]

Comment: How can I convert the dates in the database within the SQL query ?

Comment: @otus you do not need convert dates in database, you need to convert dates from textboxes to values, so  `2010-01-01` should be `40179`

Comment: I modified my query to : `strQuery = "SELECT NUM,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR,STATE,LAST_MODIFICATION_DATE,LAST_MODIFIER,CATEGORY,MODEL_LABEL FROM [MySheet$] WHERE CREATION_DATE<='" + CStr(CLng(CDate(EndDateTextBox.Value))) + "' AND CREATION_DATE>='" + CStr(CLng(CDate(BeginDateTextBox.Value))) + "'"` and I still don't get the results, I tested it with "2010-10-10" as a begin date and "2016-10-10" as end date

Comment: @you don't need convert to `Cstr` due to date in Excel is a value which is formated as date, please see my updated post

Comment: Actually I get an error message when I don't use `cstr` , "incompatible data type in criteria expression" (I translated the error message from french, it may be a bit different in english)

Comment: Ok, thanks,  I have seen your last edit, it's very weird it doesn't work for me

Comment: @otus error might be due to use `+` instead of `&` for string concatenation, replace `+` to `&` in your code. And also remove `'` in where, `'` not required in SQL when you work with integer

Comment: Still doesn't work for me, anyway I think I will look for a work around

Answer (score 0):

```
convert(datetime,CREATION_DATE,103) >= convert(datetime, BeginDateTextBox.Value ,103)
```

Do this for both the begindatetextbox and enddatetextbox

This should convert both your dates to dd/mm/yyyy format (not 100% sure if it works with dates you might need to convert to string first) so you can compare them in the same format

This is straight up sql(except for the begindatetextbox.value) so it won't work like this you will have to build up your string in code to look like this in the end

Comment: I get this error when I try this solution : error -2147214900 the "convert" function is not defined in the expression (I translated the error message from french)

Comment: alright let me find out why this isn't working and i'll get back to you

Comment: btw what kind of database do you have? mysql, oracle, access?

Comment: I use Excel files as databases and ADO to access it via the vba code

Comment: that's probably why it doesn't work, I'm going to have to look up how the convert works for excel tables

Comment: I don't really know a lot about how vba converts date but you might want to take a look at the CDATE function in vba, there is also a guide on date conversion in vba here : https://blog.udemy.com/vba-format-date/

Answer (score 0):

Try the following I saw on Microsoft Support website:

`strQuery = "SELECT NUM,CREATION_DATE,CREATOR,STATE,LAST_MODIFICATION_DATE,LAST_MODIFIER,CATEGORY,MODEL_LABEL FROM [MySheet$] WHERE CREATION_DATE<=#" + EndDateTextBox.Value + "# AND CREATION_DATE>=#" + BeginDateTextBox.Value + "#"`